# How to check if the active tab is the same tab in which the dev tools extension panel is open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Inside of my Dev Tools Panel, I connect to the content script with:

```
const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({
  active: true,
  currentWindow: true,
});

const port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id, {
 name: "bridge",
});
```

but how do I tell if the Dev Tools panel is open on `tabs[0].id` tab?

Comment: As long as port is connected the panel is open. You can use onDisconnect event of the port.